# SSIS parameter mapping to local variable

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

How do I map a parameter to a local sql variable when I do a OLE DB source using SQL Command as my data access in SSIS?

I would like to so something like this:

```
DECLARE @BeginDate datetime
DECLARE @EndDate datetime

SET @BeginDate = ?
SET @EndDate = ?

SELECT * 
FROM Blah 
WHERE date BETWEEN @BeginDate  AND @EndDate
```

but I get an error saying "Syntax error, permission violation, or other nonspecific error"

Instead of

```
SELECT * 
FROM Blah 
WHERE date BETWEEN ? AND ?
```

I have some more complicated queries and doing the later approach kills the readability.

Comment: What about a stored procedure? Have you considered this or is it an option?

Comment: This is for an OLE DB Source, have you clicked the Parameters... button to map them? Just checking the obvious first.

Comment: I did click the parameters button and got an error.  As for a stored procedure, the one database I am on needs to access data from another database and due to security reasons a linked server can not be created.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "Using Parameterized SQL Statements" section of the MDSN documentation for the [OLE DB Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141696%28v=sql.110%29.aspx#sectionToggle0) states that a parameterized query "can be a SELECT or an EXEC statement". There is no indication that a SET statement can be parameterized in the fashion you're attempting.

The obvious workaround is to put your complicated query in a stored procedure. (And, frankly, if the query is **that** complicated, future maintainers of your code will be glad that the complexity is in a stored procedure rather than being buried in the crappy code editor that SSIS provides.)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot assign '?' to datetime variable in SQL server. Assign some valid(datetime) values to the variable, and then you can use your query in SQL server task.